# View.ContextActions not firing to code behind Clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

**Problem:**

After following a few examples, [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity), [two](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38684/context-actions-how-can-you-get-the-object-for-the-row-where-the-context-action-was-executed), [three](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/Interactivity/interactivityListView/interactivityListView), I am not able to get my ContextActions to connect to my Code Behind.

This is from the examples. MenuItem_Clicked is not connecting the XAML to the code behind

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked" Text="TEST" Command="{Binding .}"/>
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

**Setup:**

I am just working with a basic example i found online. it is not a MVVM. I have the ListItems_Refresh action setup and working.

**Goal of the Code:**

When the users clicks a row, I want to open the default browser and go to the URL from the row.

I would love to know how i can troubleshoot this issue or if i have glaring typo. Thanks in advance

**Code:**

*XAML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
         x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage">
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <Label Text="60 Second Sports" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
          <ListView x:Name="rssList" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="ListItems_Refreshing">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                          <MenuItem Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked" Text="TEST" Command="{Binding .}"/>
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <StackLayout>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Font="8"/>
                            <!--<Label Text="{Binding Description}" Font="6"/>-->
                            <Label Text="{Binding PublishedDate}" Font="5"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Link}" Font="5"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

*Code Behind*

```
    private void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("button was clicked");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");
    }


    protected void ListItems_Refreshing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("refresh triggered");

        //doRefresh(); 
        //my method for repopulating the list ImageListView.EndRefresh(); 
        //this is a very important step. It will refresh forever without triggering it }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: @G.hakim When the user clicks on the listview row i want to redirect to a URL

Comment: And why are you not using the item tapped event for that?

Comment: The attribute must be CommandParameter not Command [xamarin doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity)

Comment: @G.hakim i wasn't even aware it was a thing. Thanks for the insight. Got it all working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open a browser when you click on a ListView item, you can just listen to the `ItemTapped` event.

> ItemTapped fires when an item is tapped.

So, in your ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="rssList" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
          ItemTapped="listItemTapped" 
          Refreshing="ListItems_Refreshing">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Font="8"/>
                            <!--<Label Text="{Binding Description}" Font="6"/>-->
                            <Label Text="{Binding PublishedDate}" Font="5"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Link}" Font="5"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

And, the listener method.

```
 public void listItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
 {
       Console.WriteLine("button was clicked");
       var item = (YourModel)e.Item;
 }
```

Comment: Wow. That was easier than i expected. Thanks for the help. Didn't even know the ItemTapped was a thing.